# ReactiveUI routing and Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, reactiveui

I'm continuing ReactiveUI explorations on Windows Phone, and have came to a moment where I need to do a navigation between pages. Obviously, I want to do this with the ReactiveUI. Unfortunately, googling (and binging) around didn't give any samples on that. The most useful thing I was able to find is "Play for Windows" on GitHub, which have the routing implemented. But I don't think that technique could apply to the Windows Phone programming, since navigation between WP pages is very different from desktop stuff. In Play, as far as I understand, navigation is basically done by switching visibility of different UserControls. I don't think it's a proper way to do things in WP.

On the other hand, looking at the ReactiveUI sources, I see that WP7 routing code indeed is the same as the desktop one. This leads me to a confusion.

So my question is, how ReactiveUI.Routing is intended to be used on WP7? Also it would be very nice to have some samples, best practices, whatever, to take a look at.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no special affordances for WP7's broken View-based routing that you *have* to use - you'll have to build this piece yourself (You don't have to use RxUI.Routing to use ReactiveUI, it's an optional feature)

If you build it in a reusable way though and would like to include it in ReactiveUI, let me know!

Comment: Okay, I see. What I'm really missing now is how RxUI.Routing works. Therefore, I'm not sure that I need to use it for building WP7 navigation stuff. I'll take a closer look at how Play works for that, but maybe you have another good samples available?
And in general, how do you think, could or should WP7 page to page navigation be implemented through / based on RxUI.Routing?

Comment: I'm actually saying, that you need to forget about RxUI.Routing completely and build your own solution around WP7 native routing (since you *have* to use it on WP7). I'm not familiar enough with how WP7 works to build a routing solution for it

Comment: Okay, that's clear. I've had a look RxUI.Routing sources today, and I think that probably it will be possible to use the same approach for WP7. I mean, to keep the interfaces same, but make different implementation for some classes. I'm certainly considering contributing WP7 Routing back to RxUI, since I really like this project and it's approach to building UI as state machine. I'm just not sure if I'll be able to pull this thing alone. But I think I'm going to try.

Comment: Even if it's not complete, contribute it anyways and I can fix it up