# ReactiveUI routing on Windows Phone (Universal App)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, reactiveui, win-universal-app

I'm working on moving some WPF code to Windows Universal app and I'm using ReactiveUI.

From the [ReactiveUI 6 migration guide](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/docs/migrating-from-rxui5.md):

> > Several Routing classes that never worked properly have been removed, and routing is Generally Discouraged from being used in anything other than a WPF app.

Does this General Discouragement™ mean I should not use RoutedViewHost in a universal app, or is this referring to something else?

1. [This question about WP7 leads me to believe that it shouldn't be used.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445763/reactiveui-routing-and-windows-phone)
2. [This question about WP8 makes me think it should work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103266/implementing-tab-like-navigation-model-in-windows-phone-8-how) (Other than the reference to ReactiveUI.Mobile, which doesn't exist anymore.)

My universal app contains a single Page with a RoutedViewHost, (basically, the same setup as #2) but when I tap the hardware back button my app exits no matter how deep into the navigation stack I am.  I'm not sure whether I've done something wrong, or if this just doesn't work for universal apps and I should convert to Frame / Page nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that handling of the back button changed in Universal Apps.  I added some code in App.xaml.cs to handle the hardware BackPressed event and pop the RoutingState's navigation stack and it works as expected.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639128.aspx